# Can I get an istream to emplace rather than assign?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, tokenize, istream, emplace

The istream `operator>>`'s require a reference to an existing object. That means what they do is assignment rather than in-place construction, right?

Well, how can I skip the initial construction? Maybe the compiler can optimize it away, but I may still be required to provide parameters I would rather not need to. Can this be done with istreams at all?

... I would like to be able to have, say,

```
template <typename T> void emplace_from(std::istream stream, T* place);
```

work for all types for T for which `stream >> my_t_variable` works. Although, admittedly, this function declaration looks a bit ugly.

Comment: Not with standard facilities AFAIK. Could you give an example of the syntax you wish to achieve ?

Comment: The standard `emplace` calls a constructor. You pass constructor arguments to it, and it forwards them to the constructor. Your proposed `emplace` cannot construct anything because it has no idea how to extract constructor arguments out of a stream. It has no idea *which* constructor to use!

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with the extraction operator (`std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, T&)`).

But with `std::istream` in general, sure. Simply, implement a function `T extract(std::istream&)` or similar instead. It can be implemented almost identically to the extraction operator: Read the character stream, initialize a new object using the input, return the object. Then you can simply call: `T t = extract(std::cin)`.

Comment: "simply"... if I have implement that, I don't need istreams at all... :-(

Comment: @einpoklum i don't quite follow you. Why wouldn't you need istreams at all?

Comment: using istreams lets me convert a string into any type (for which someone has bothered to implement operator>>). Without them, I need to implement conversions not just for the types I know of, but for whatever types my templated code will be used with ever in the future.

Comment: @einpoklum and analoguously, istreams let you convert a string to any type for which someone has bothered to implement `extract`.

Comment: Yes, the thing is people know they should implement the extraction, but don't know they should implement my dreamt-up operation.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, being a standard convention is a significant advantage to the use of stream extreaction operator. But as I said, what you're asking for cannot be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

```c++
#include <experimental/optional>

namespace exp = std::experimental;

template<class T, class charT>
exp::optional<T> extract(std::basic_istream<charT>& is) {
    auto it = std::istream_iterator<T, charT>(is);
    if (it != decltype(it)()) {
        return *it;
    }
    return exp::optional<T>{};
}

int main()
{
    int i = *extract<int>(std::cin);
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Note that this requires `T` to be default constructible, so it won't help in the case of `but I may still be required to provide parameters I would rather not need to` which I think implies that `T` is in fact, not default constructible.

Comment: @user2079303 Then one should throw an exception or return nullptr.